# Xcode wont play sound in this folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi this is a simple app to play a sound when a button is pressed. I imported the frameworks and the folder with a whole host of sounds, but when I set the path it wont play the sound and I get an NSE exception error when I click on the button to play the sound. So i took the sound file out of the folder even though that folder is in my project and it magically plays? any ideas? or what extra code I must add in order to play from a folder?

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;


- (IBAction)Yes:(id)sender {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"yes" ofType:@"mp3"]];



    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]   initWithContentsOfURL:url error:NULL];

    [theAudio play];



}
@end
```

Comment: What is the exception? Can you share the stack? Also show the file tree if possible (that is, are you sure yes.mp3 is at the top level of your bundle?)

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by bundle and the excetions is an NSE eception meaning it cant locate the files if  iput them in the sound folder only when they are taken out is when it finds them. The folder is imported to the project so i dont think that would be the problem but idk?

Answer (score 0):

This is an opportunity for you to learn about both exceptions and bundles/files:

First, Exceptions: 
[NSException](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/index.html) is the root class of all exceptions, and by itself is not a useful way to describe what is happening. Take a look at the linked reference, where you can see which properties are available to describe what went wrong. These properties are available for inspection from within Xcode. Best way (IMO) is with the automatic breakpoint on exceptions. Simply choose "Add Exception Breakpoint" from the + button at the bottom-left of the Breakpoint Navigator (the vertical bar on the left side of Xcode).

Second, Bundles:
Bundles (for our purposes) are really just a special kind of directory. When you use `[NSBundle mainBundle]`, you are referring to your application's "top level" directory. There are several useful methods on [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:) to help you locate resources. One of them even includes taking a subdirectory as a parameter (hint!)

As a bonus, I feel it would be good to also mention Stack Overflow and hopefully encourage habits that improve question quality, which in turns promotes answer frequency and quality. If you are experiencing an exception and it's fundamental to your question, please include the full exception details. If you are working with files and they are not loading properly, please include an explanation (perhaps a screenshot from finder) of how the files are organized on the resultant device (tip: you can find the application files for the simulator. just set a breakpoint and inspect the value of a path returned from one of NSBundle's methods).